# how to make Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT to open gallery without showing popup that asks for options like BLUETOOTH FILE TRANSFER and GALLERY?

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open gallery directly in Action_Get_Content but it shows a popup that asks for the options like Select picture BLUETOOTH FILE TRANSFER and GALLERY. if any one can help me i would be so thankful to him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

without you know the package name of Your Phone's gallery app,a popup dialog will always be displayed.

if you get the package name ,intent.setPackage(name) will help you start the gallery directly.

Comment: how can i get package name of phone's gallery app??

Comment: If you just want to get your phone's package,start the gallery and see the logcat,a message with tag ActivityManager and content "Start {flat=xxx  cmp=xxxxxxx}" will be shown ,the cmp is a ComponentName object from which you can get the package name and class name.

Comment: Thnx for your answer it helped me. :)